# JCache Infinspan creates immortals on entry update

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly-10, infinispan, jcache

While using JCache (Infinispan) on Wildfly 10.1 I stumbled against the following issue. I created a new cache (test-cache) where I used CreatedExpiryPolicy with a duration of 5 minutes.

After playing around with the cache I noticed that if I put the same key twice the cache entry will be converted to an ImmortalCacheEntry and therefore the entry will stick in the cache forever. I know I can work around this issue by using remove and put for updates but for me this sounds like a bug in Infinspan.

The JavaDoc in CreatedExpiryPolicy clearly says that updates have no affect on the current expiry duration.

```
CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
CacheManager cacheManager = cachingProvider.getCacheManager();

MutableConfiguration<Object, Object> config = new MutableConfiguration<>()
        .setTypes(Object.class, Object.class)
        .setStoreByValue(true)
        .setStatisticsEnabled(true)
        .setManagementEnabled(true)
        .setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(new Duration(TimeUnit.MINUTES, 5)));

Cache<Object, Object> cache = cacheManager.createCache("test-cache", config);

cache.put("key", "value"); // MortalCacheEntry{key=key, value=value}}

cache.put("key", "value"); // ImmortalCacheEntry{key=key, value=value}}
```

Excerpt from javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public Duration getExpiryForUpdate() {
    //updating a cache entry has no affect on the current expiry duration
    return null;
}
```

Can anybody help my clarify if this is a bug or if I am using it wrong? If it is a bug I will create a new JIRA issue.

Comment: What Infinispan version are you using? In the latest Infinispan 9.2.0.CR2 we have added JCache 1.1 compatibility and wondering if the same issue still persists.

Comment: I am using version Infinispan 8.2.4.Final that is included in Wildfly 10.1.0.Final and JCache 1.0.0.

Comment: Confirmed; AbstractJCache, line 242: if expiration policy returns `null` or eternal, the default policy in Infinispan (eternal) is used.
9.2 contains reworked version, but the problem persists there. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-8841

Comment: As a workaround: have you tried an expiry policy that works the way it should?

Comment: Thanks for confirming the bug. Yes, as a workaround I'm using putIfAbsent method or modified expiry policy, both options are okay for my use cases.